# Recibir y mostrar un array de C# en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, array

Tengo un *array* de C# que necesito mostrar al entrar a una página determinada. Estoy realizando una petición con AJAX para recibir estos datos.

```
$.post({
        url: '/Home/MostrarArray',
        success: function (datas) {
            console.log(datas);
        }
    });
```

Siendo estos mi petición AJAX y:

```
[HttpPost]
public string[] MostrarArray()
{
    string[] matArray = new string[] { "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro" };

    Array.Sort(matArray);
    return matArray;
}
```

La función a la que llamo.

Lo que me devuelve (lo que `console.log(datas)` muestra) es un *String*, literalmente: `System.String[]`

No tengo muy claro cómo hacer para que devuelva el array y no el "tipo" de dato... ¿Alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @Pikoh Si aparece `System.String[]` no le están llegando los datos bien, `console.log`es capaz de mostrar un array de strings correctamente. System no existe en Javascript

Comment: Como ha dicho @Pikoh, he comprobado si me enviaba los datos correctamente. Con `datas[0]` me devuelve una "S", también probé con `typeof(datas)` y, efectivamente, me dice que es string

Comment: @PabloLozano hmm..claro,aqui el problema es que es un array de C#, no de javascript, por eso console.log no podrá mostrarlo.

Comment: Pikoh, al añadir el `dataType: 'json' ` entra en el error de la petición (al no devolver nada he probado a añadirle una función en el error)

Comment: La cuestión básica es que no puedes devolver un tipo específico de .net, debes devolver los datos en json. Usa la librería json.net y devuelve el array en json

Comment: Vale, no había pensado en ello... He pasado los datos del array a un json y lo los he enviado de esa manera como has dicho y ha funcionado perfectamente, ya puedo leerlos y mostrarlos. Si quieres puedes desarrollarlo como respuesta. Gracias! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript (JQuery en este caso) no entiende los tipos nativos de C# (en este caso, `string[]`).

Para efectuar el retorno de parámetros en estos casos, lo mejor es serializar el valor a devolver como `json`(usando por ejemplo `Json.NET`), y recibirlos de la misma manera usando `datatype: 'json'`